# JavaFX - SceneBuilder TreItem

Tags: javafx, treeview, scenebuilder

I wanted to make a `TreeView` in SceneBuilder but I cannot find the `TreeItem` component needed to fill it. Am I blind or what have I missed?

I am using SceneBuilder 8.4.1.

Comment: Seems to me that `TreeItem` is considered a "model" class rather than "view" class. You probably have to do it in the controller class.

Comment: Jai is correct. Once you've added the `TreeView` control to you scene, you need to use the controller to actually populate it with `TreeItems`.  Just like a `TableView` doesn't allow you to add items to it directly in SceneBuilder.

Comment: @Zephyr okay thanks. Seems a bit weird to me since you can add `MenuItem`s to a `Menu` but what do I know. Thanks anyway.